# is it possible, to get a props and pass it as a parameter to a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, reducers

I'm trying to get a props from MapsStateToProps via react-redux's connect, then passing it to a child component. This prop is used as an argument to a function, the function is responsible returning something, that something then becomes the state of the child component.

I know the props is getting updated, because I have it displayed within the child component, however at the place where it's used as an argument it does not update right away. I have to navigate to another component (react-routers), then come back to the original component to see the desired result as a result of the function using the props.

Is there a way to have the change occur without going to another component and then coming back? Obviously I'm doing something wrong, *or* what I'm trying to do isn't the react way? Any tips?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import filterData from "../../States/AllStates/filterData"
import BookComponent from "./BookComponent";

const mapStateToProps = state => { 
    return {
    fmlProps: state.ReducerName.fmlProps
    }
};

class Testing extends Component {
    state = {
        // this.props.fmlPropsdoesn't work right away. You need to go away then come back 
        // to see the desired result, which I want to avoid
        XXX: filterData(this.props.fmlProps) 
    }
    render() { 
        return (
            <>

            <h1>{this.props.fmlProps}</h1> {/* this show up correct */}

            {this.state.XXX.map(FakeData => (
            <BookComponent
            key={FakeData.planNumber}
            PNum={FakeData.planNumber}
            PName={FakeData.planName}
            />))}

            </>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null) (Testing);
```

Comment: You could use getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle method to update your state with the new prop.

Comment: @FarhanHaque but getDerivedStateFromProps I thought is used from sending something to the reducer, or dispatching/ grabbing an action then sending it to update the reducer. I'm already doing that from another component, that technically not even a parent of this, rather a distant component. I didn't think getDerivedStateFromProps  is necessary here.
Sir, are you certain?

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps is used to update the state based on new props. Yes, you can give it a try.

Comment: @FarhanHaque i just updated m y code it did not work... what excatly would you have to place in the getDerivedStateFromProps  when there is nothing to dispatch from this component?

Comment: <h1>{this.props.fmlProps}</h1> {/* this show up correct */} 
Why don't you use the props directly? You can call filterData(this.props.fmlProps) inside the render method and use its value to iterate over. getDerivedStateFromProps would also work but it is an anti-pattern and should be used sparingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use componentDidUpdate to check and invoke function when the component has been updated.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.fmlProps !== prevProps.fmlProps) {
    //invoke function and setstate
    const tmp =  XXX: filterData(this.props.fmlProps) 
    this.setState({XXX})
  }
}
```

More read here - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: DUDE you are a life savor!  thank you so much, yes this was EXCATLY what my code required. best wishes sir.